# Visitor/Listener pattern confusion in -Dlanguage=TypeScript

Tags: typescript, antlr4

I am investigating moving from antlr4ts to the main Typescript target. The [documentation for the Typescript target](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/typescript-target.md) says Visitors and Listeners are defined differently ...

```
class CustomVisitor extends MyGrammarVisitor {
  visitRuleName(ctx: ParserRuleContext) {
    // code here ...
  }
}
```

```
class CustomListener extends MyGrammarListener {
    exitRuleName = (ctx: ParserRuleContext) => {
        // code here...
    }
}
```

However it appears that both listeners and visitors as defined in the typescript target are expected to be properties and not member functions.

This is the forum requested by the ANTLR maintainers for asking questions, so is the documentation correct, or is the code correct? Should I code to the actual generated parser (and submit a PR to fix the documentation) or does the documentation describe the intended behavior and I should file a bug against the implementation?

---- ADDED AFTER SOME HOURS ----

It appears to me that the documentaion is wrong in both cases, the correct code should be very similar to the way this was written in antlr4ts:

```
class CustomVisitor
  extends ParseTreeVisitor<T>
  implements MyGrammarVisitor<T> {
```

And similarly for the listeners. Question still remains, am I correct and should I try and fix the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a documentation bug. Please submit a PR and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

While Alex' answer is totally valid, it misses the point a bit. The question is about the different documented implementations. And the short answer is: the documentation is wrong. Both, visitors and listeners use the same approach, namely unassigned instance properties. The main reason is this: listeners and visitors both provide a way to hook into tree generation and tree walking. They contain a property for each possible rule entry and exit point (or just the rule itself in a visitor), which can be a large number, depending on the grammar they are for.

Usually, you are interested in only a couple of those and it would be a tremendous burden if you had to add empty method bodies for anything that you don't want, just to satisfy an interface.

With the unassigned properties this is not necessary. Just assign methods where you need them and ignore the others. The generated parser contains code to check this, like:

```js
    public exitRule(listener: ANTLRv4ParserListener): void {
        if (listener.exitRuleSpec) {
             listener.exitRuleSpec(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

*(Disclaimer: I know nothing of `antlr4`, but I beleive this question is generalizable)*

Typically in Typescript, classes should use member function syntax unless there's a good reason not to.

And one good reason to use assigned instance properties instead is if you need a unique identity for that function.

```
class Foo { foo() {} }
console.log(new Foo().foo === new Foo().foo) // true
```

This is `true` because when you use the member function all instances will share a reference to that same function.

```
class Bar { bar = () => {} }
console.log(new Bar().bar === new Bar().bar) // false
```

This is `false` because now the function is created and assigned to that property when the class is instantiated.

---

And one place this typically matters is event handlers. When removing an event handler, you have to know which one to remove.

```
listener.add('click', foo.onClick)
listener.add('click', bar.onClick)

// then, later...
listener.remove('click', foo.onClick) // just remove foo.onClick
```

Here the identity of that function must be unique to the foo object or it would remove all event handlers for that class, which is likely not what you want.

---

I'm guessing that's what's going on here. The event handler function needs to have a unique identity per instance so it can be removed later by looking up that identity.

But for visitors that simply get called, that's not really necessary because they will just be directly called by `myInstance.visitRuleName(...)`. You could use a `visitRuleName = () => {}` style there if you want, at the cost of some minor performance overhead to have a unique version of that function in every instance, and it should work fine.

So given all that, I'd say the documentation is correct and you should use `foo() {}` for visitors, and `foo = () => {}` for listeners.

Comment: Thanks for the post. The documentation does not describe the code. In the code, both are expecting properties, not member functions. Either the documentation is wrong, or the implementation of visitors is wrong. I'm coding as if the documentation is wrong, but posting this to know what to do to make the world better.

I am also curious why they didn't use member functions, but I don't even know how/where to ask that.

Comment: _"The documentation does not describe the code"_ What code? What _exactly_ are you seeing that doesn't match the documentation?

Comment: This is where "I don't understand antlr" is the problem. I'm fine with your answer, I marked it helpful.

Antlr is a java executable which generates a unique parser based on a language grammar. It also generates a visitor and a listener for walking parse trees generated by the parser.

The linked documentation gives a brief example of how to use the generated listener and visitor. The actual generated visitor uses the member-property pattern, like the documented listener and actual listener do.

Comment: So you are saying the generated code is like `{ visitor = () => {}, listener = () => {} }` and the docs say it should be `{ visitor() {}, listener = () => {} }`? If so, then I would expect both styles will work for the visitor since the differences shouldn't really matter there. But I would expect listeners to require the property assignment syntax to work correctly. I'd encourage you try it out for yourself though. It's entirely possible that the docs are just wrong or inconsistent and both forms work equally well.

Comment: Also, the [typescript] tag has 133,000 watchers, and the [antlr4] tag has 500. So I figured some educated guesses was better for you than the sound of crickets.

Comment: yeah i appreciate the effort. it turns out, if you define the base class as a member you can extend it with a property but if you define the base class as a property typescript generates an error when you extend it with a member, so it does matter. i suspect the code is correct and the docs are wrong.